# Best solution for $(A+B)\cdot X = C$

Tags: matrices, optimization, matrix-equations, dynamic-programming, programming

Suppose I am given a matrix $A_{1×3}$ and another matrix $C$. I have to find the best possible solution of the form $(A + B)\cdot X = C$. But the solution will be considered best only if

1. $X_{3×3}$ is a diagonal matrix, more better if it is an identity matrix of the form constant$\cdot I_{3×3}$
2. And matrix $B_{1×3}$ is such that $B = [b_1 \space \space b_2 \space \space b_3]$ where either $b_1=b_2$ or $b_2=b_3$ or $b_1=b_3$ or $b_1=b_2=b_3$ (best).

Here is an example: 
$A = [2 \space \space 8 \space \space 45]$,
$C = [9 \space \space 27 \space \space  46]$

So in this case the best solution will be $B = [1 \space \space 1 \space \space 1]$ and

$$X=\begin{bmatrix}
3&0&0\\
0&3&0\\
0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}$$
In matrix $X$ also we should try to make $a_{1,1}=a_{2,2}=a_{3,3}$. The attempt should be made to find values such that $b = [0 \space \space 0 \space \space 0]$ and $X = k \cdot I_{3×3}$
or $B = [n \space \space n \space \space n]$ and $X = I_{3×3}$.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: @saulspatz will learn it, but the solution plesae ?

Comment: Write your question so I can read it, and I will look at it again.

Comment: @saulspatz done

Comment: @AK10 I must apologize.  I have deleted my two comments and my *answer*.  I **totally misinterpreted** your posting.  I thought that you were looking for ABX = C, when instead you are looking for (A+B)X = C.  **My bad.**

Comment: Does the first point take priority?  That is, is any solution where $X$ is diagonal best, regardless of the form of $B$?

Comment: Or are you saying that only solutions where $X$ is a scalar matrix (a constant time the identity matrix) are to be considered, and the ranking is actually done according to point $2$?

Answer (score 0):

Let $x_1, x_2, x_3$ be the diagonal elements of $X$. Assuming that $b_1 = b_2 = b_3 =b$, this reduces to the system of equations
$$(a_1 + b)x_1 = c_1\\(a_2 + b)x_2 = c_2\\(a_3 + b)x_3 = c_3$$

This is three equations in four unknowns. If you pick any $b$ other than $b = -a_1, b= -a_2, b= -a_3$, you will have a unique solution with 
$$x_i = \frac {c_i}{a_i + b}. \quad i = 1,2,3$$

Now if you also want $x_1 = x_2 = x_3 = x$, then instead we get three equations in only two unknowns, which can only have solutions when the equations are not independent. In particular when these ratios are equal:
$$\frac {c_1 - c_2}{a_1 - a_2} = \frac {c_2 - c_3}{a_2 - a_3} = \frac {c_3 - c_1}{a_3 - a_1}$$
$x$ is then the common value, and $b = \frac {c_i}x - a_i$ for any $i$.